# Bijections from $\dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[x, y]}{\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}$ to $S^{1}\cap \mathbb{Q^{2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

i'm trying to solve this exercise:

Consider the ring $A=\dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[x, y]}{\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}.$

$a)$ Show that exists a bijection between the set of all ring morphism $f:A\to \mathbb{Q}$ and rational points of circle $x^2+y^2=1$;

$b)$ Determine the generators of $\operatorname{ker}f,$ where $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ is the morphism given by $\bar{x}\to i$ and $\bar{y}\to \sqrt{2}$.

So, I know that is a isomorphism $A \simeq \mathbb{Q}\Big[\dfrac{2t}{1+t^{2}},\dfrac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\Big]$ and the field of fractions of $A$ is $\mathbb{Q}(t).$ But how to use that in this exercise? I'm to define an application
$$\alpha:A\to\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Q}^{2} \ ; \ a^{2}+b^2=1\}$$
given by
$\alpha(\bar{f})=\Big(\dfrac{2\psi(\bar{f})}{1+\psi(\bar{f})^{2}},\dfrac{1-\psi(\bar{f})^{2}}{1+\psi(\bar{f})^{2}}\Big).$
I guess I need to fix a point. I can't conclude anything. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** Set $I=(x^2+y^2-1)$.

If $P=(a,b)$ is a rational point of the circle, show that evaluation at $(x,y)=(a,b)$ induces a morphism $e_P:f(x,y) +I\in A\mapsto f(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras.

Conversely, if $e:A\to\mathbb{Q}$ is a morphism, set $a=f(x +I)$ and $b=f(y+I).$ Show that $P_e:=(a,b)$ is a rational point of the circle.

Show that the two assignemnts $P\rightsquigarrow e_P$ and $e\rightsquigarrow P_e$ are mutually inverse.

For the second question, divide $f$ by $x^2+1$ to write it as $g(y)+h(y)x$. Then divide $g$ and $h$ by $y^2-2$...

**Nota bene.** Your isomorphism  $A \simeq \mathbb{Q}\Big[\dfrac{2t}{1+t^{2}},\dfrac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\Big]$ is dubious...How would you obtain the point $(0,-1) ?$

Comment: Thank you @GreginGre. I got item $a)$. About item $b)$ if $f\in \operatorname{ker}$ can be written in this form $f=(x-i)g(x,y)+ h(y)(y-\sqrt{2})+r, g\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y],h\in\mathbb{Q}[y], r\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\bar{r}=0.$ Then what I need to do?

Comment: Better :$r=0$. Can't you find generators of the kernel ? Don't you see an ideal whichi would be the obvious candidate for the kernel ?

Comment: Ooh, thank you. Now I guess the generators are $x-i$ and $y-\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Your approach for the second question doesn't make sense: neither $i$ nor $\sqrt{2}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @math54321 you have a reason.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that $A$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. I will propose another hint, then...

Comment: @Kalashinikov: certainly the evaluation map $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}$ sending $x \mapsto i$, $y \mapsto \sqrt{2}$ has kernel $(x - i, y - \sqrt{2})$. Now think about what happens when you restrict to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and pass to the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \twoheadrightarrow A$